# Inject javascript to Adobe Pro DC

Tags: adobe, acrobat

How to automate injecting custom javascript code to Adobe Pro DC?

I checked in the https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_developer_guide.pdf, but I don't see anything related to automating.

Comment: The is no Acrobat Reader Pro. Do you mean Acrobat Pro DC or Acrobat Reader DC? Acrobat Reader DC cannot be automated. Acrobat Pro DC will allow scripts to write scripts into many interactive objects.

Comment: @joelgeraci, thanks for correcting me. I have edited the question. Is there a way we can inject scripts in an automated manner and run in javascript console?

Comment: Ok - Are you asking if an external application or developer tool can add scripts to PDF files that then run in Acrobat or are you asking if you can use Acrobat to automate adding scripts to PDF files?

Comment: I am asking the first point @joelgeraci. I want to highlight or create bounding boxes on different pdf files and the coordinates might vary for each file and I want to take the inputs of the coordinates from CSV and inject it to the javascript console of Acrobat Pro in an automated manner.

Comment: You can't inject JavaScript into the console. However, you can... though it is horrifying... use Windows VBA or macOS AppleScript to "eval()" a string that is actually JavaScript. You might want to consider using a library tool instead though. Adding highlight annotations to a PDF is fairly trivial using any number of PDF library tools.